# Check Shutdown Privilege

Tags: shutdown, c++, privileges

I'm trying to make a C++ program on Ubuntu that checks if a user can shutdown the PC, and, if so, shut it down for him.

So, I'm thinking about getting the user ID, and then, checking if, or if not, he has the rights to shut down the computer.

However, I really don't know what is the critera in Ubuntu that says if a user has such a right ... do you happen to know what this is ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to my problem, so now I'm posting it.

Testing admin privileges can be done like so :

```
uid_t uid = getuid(), euid = geteuid();
if(uid < 0 || uid != euid) {
    // Can stop or reboot system
} else {
    // Cannot stop nor reboot system
}
```